# Getting client ip from UDP connection C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I currently have a server application that is listening on a port for UDP packets. When one is sent to the server, it receives it properly and processes it. Is there any way I can get the ip address of where the packet came from?

Here is how I create the socket

```
this.UDPListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
this.UDPListener.Bind(endPoint);

SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs(); 
socketEventArgs.SetBuffer(this.ReceiveBuffer, 0, this.ReceiveBuffer.Length);
socketEventArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnReceive);
if (!this.UDPListener.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArgs))
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((Object o) => this.OnReceive(this, socketEventArgs)));
```

When the OnReceive is called there is nothing that contains the ip where the message came from. I haved looked through the SocketAsyncEventArgs and all I see is the listening ip.

Edit:

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
this.UDPListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
this.UDPListener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port));

EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
this.UDPListener.BeginReceiveFrom(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref remoteEndPoint, OnReceive, this.UDPListener);
```

Then in the OnReceive heres how to get the data and info

```
//Get the received message.
Socket receiveSocket = (Socket)AsyncResult.AsyncState;
EndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
int udpMessageLength = receiveSocket.EndReceiveFrom(AsyncResult, ref clientEndPoint);
byte[] udpMessage = new byte[udpMessageLength];
Array.Copy(ReceiveBuffer, udpMessage, udpMessageLength);

//Start listening for a new message.
EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Int32.Parse(((IPEndPoint)receiveSocket.LocalEndPoint).Port.ToString()));
this.UDPListener.BeginReceiveFrom(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref remoteEndPoint, OnReceive, this.UDPListener);

//Handle the received message
Debug.WriteLine("Recieved {0} bytes from {1}:{2} to {3}:{4}", udpMessageLength, ((IPEndPoint)clientEndPoint).Address, ((IPEndPoint)clientEndPoint).Port, ((IPEndPoint)receiveSocket.LocalEndPoint).Address, ((IPEndPoint)receiveSocket.LocalEndPoint).Port);
```

Comment: There is a good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5795658/397817

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about `UdpClient`, but if you use the `Socket` class directly, you can call the `.ReceiveFrom(byte[], ref EndPoint)` method, and receive the remote address via the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the `ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo` field in the arguments.

```
    void OnReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        var info = e.ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo;
        byte[] address = info.Address.GetAddressBytes();
    }
```

Comment: info.Address is null for me for some reason

Comment: strange; what is `Address` null if you replace `e.ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo` with `(IPEndPoint)e.RemoteEndPoint`?

Comment: e.RemoteEndPoint is null too. i wasn't sure if you just couldn't do it with UDP or what. it seems like that info should be there somewhere

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147542/c-udp-socket-get-receiver-address

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.remoteendpoint.aspx the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` contains a RemoteEndPoint property that contains the other end.  Is there anything in there?

Comment: Nope, null too. This is where I started looking, not sure why its not coming across.