# Is this ReceiveFromAsync() bug?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udp

this is my first question and I'm not English native speaker so sorry for my (maybe) inaccurate English.

I'm implementing real-time network engine and using Socket.xxxAsync() method.

I made a UDP socket at server-side like this.

```
m_udpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
m_udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, udpPort));
SocketAsyncEventArgs udpRecvArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
udpRecvLoopStart(m_udpSock, udpRecvArg);
```

(udpPort is known to client.)

```
    private void udpRecvLoopStart(Socket udpSocket, SocketAsyncEventArgs udpRecvArg)
    {            
        udpRecvArg.AcceptSocket = udpSocket;
        byte[] udpRecvBuffer = new byte[NetworkEngineConst.MsgSizeMax];
        udpRecvArg.SetBuffer(udpRecvBuffer, 0, udpRecvBuffer.Length);
        udpRecvArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        udpRecvArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(udpRecvArg_Completed);

        udpRecv(udpRecvArg);
    }

    private void udpRecv(SocketAsyncEventArgs udpRecvArg)
    { 
        bool synchronous = false;
        try
        {                
            synchronous = !udpRecvArg.AcceptSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(udpRecvArg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnIOError("recvUdp()\n" + e.ToString());
            return;
        }
        if (synchronous)
            udpRecvArg_Completed(this, udpRecvArg);
    }
```

Completed event handler is this:

```
    void udpRecvArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs udpRecvArg)
    {
        EndPoint udpEp = udpRecvArg.RemoteEndPoint;            
        string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(udpRecvArg.Buffer, 14, udpRecvArg.BytesTransferred - 14);
        Debug.WriteLine(udpEp + " " + msg);
        udpRecv(udpRecvArg);            
    }
```

( first 14 bytes are message prefix,CRC and sequence number)

And two(or more) clients send UDP packet to server.
( sending rate is hundreds per second )

For example, client1(192.168.0.1:50113) sends "11111111111111111111111111111", 
client2(192.168.0.1:59368) sends "2".

But sometimes(not always) endpoint is wrong. log is like below:

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:59368 2

192.168.0.1:59368 2

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

**192.168.0.1:59368 11111111111111111111111111111** <- wrong part

192.168.0.1:59368 2

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:59368 2

192.168.0.1:50113 11111111111111111111111111111

192.168.0.1:59368 2

192.168.0.1:59368 2

I doubt packet error, but there was no error in packet(I confirmed with Wireshark)

Is this a bug ?

(Add)

I tried

```
        m_udpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        m_udpSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
        m_udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, udpPort));
```

and replaced ReceiveFromAsync() with ReceiveMessageFromAsync().

but SocketAsyncEventArgs.ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo.Address is null

(Add)
ReceiveMessageFromAsync() problem is a bug.

It is fixed in the .NET framework 4.0

[here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543700/net-framework-3-5-socket-receivemessagefrom-leaves-ippacketinformation-empty)

thank you.

Comment: I have updated right now. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using [Socket.ReceiveMessageFromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivemessagefromasync.aspx) and then get the packet data using [ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.receivemessagefrompacketinfo.aspx) .

FYI [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752604/getting-client-ip-from-udp-connection-c) is an alternative way to do it (see the Edit in the answer)

HTH

Comment: ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo.Address is null and ReceiveMessageFromPacketInfo.interface is 0